# Loading component on button click in Angular7

Tags: angular7, gwtbootstrap3

How can I make edit button work in a data table in angular 7. I would also like to know how to load a component on button click,

Comment: Just to make use of any button u can use (click)="methodname()"

Comment: I have add button in one component that is Manage clients component and I want to load Add clients component when the add button on Manage clients component is clicked. Hope you understand.

Comment: This is called 'lazy loading'. The [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) has a good example.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is my idea to acheive it

First for a button to work we use (click)

```
<button (click)="toggledata()">Show</button>
<demo-component *ngIf="value"></demo-component>
```

.ts

```
value = false;

toggledata() {
 this.value = !this.value;
}
```